# Using Elasticsearch service in Bitbucket pipeline

Tags: laravel, docker, elasticsearch, continuous-integration, bitbucket-pipelines

I have added the elasticsearch service in my bitbucket pipeline.

Please find the code below.

```
elasticsearch:
  image: xiting/elasticsearch-bitbucket-pipeline
  variables:
    ES_JAVA_OPTS: '-Xms512m -Xmx512m'
```

But I am getting the below error while running my tests.

```
Elasticsearch\Common\Exceptions\RuntimeException: Could not parse host:
```

Can anyone please guide how can we add elasticsearch as a service in the bitbucket pipeline?